# How to make the form completely transparent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I already made the background transparent but there is still some part left from the group box. How do I make those transparent also?

The blank line are what I want it to be transparent. It should give you the picture of what I want. Thanks.
[image]

**And don't even ask what are the password for, all of them are just dummies :)**

If you want to see and edit the code, [here](http://snote.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Chances are that problem is out of your hands. Someone correct me if I am wrong though...

Comment: What technologies are you using Windows Forms, WPF, something else?

Comment: I don't think so, language like these always have a solution. And I say always even you need some help from DLLs and stuff. At time.

Comment: Windows Forms, and I can transfer to WPF if need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how the GroupBox control works. The Background property of that control includes the area that your screenshot points to. If you wanted to do a workaround for it, you should set the GroupBox background to be transparent as well, and draw a white box behind it, encompassing only the area you want to be white.

Comment: I will see about that. Wait a sec.

Comment: Got it working, but your idea have a flaw in it. The name of the group box can't be seen after applying the idea. So I decided to remove the name altogether.

Comment: You can also "Shape" your form using the form's "Region" property. if you are looking to make a custom non-square shape this might be a solution. THis will also affect the controls on your form regardless of their transparencies.

Comment: You may also try setting the Background of the Group box to its parent value, thus making it look like whatever is "behind" it.

Answer (score 0):

[Form.Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx) doesn't work for you?

Comment: I want it to completely disappeared. And I only want the boarders and not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

What is the GroupBox's parent container? Is it a Form or a Panel? Is that element also set to transparent? As a test I made a GroupBox and placed it on top of (inside) a Panel. I changed the background color of the Panel to red and the background color of the GroupBox to transparent and those ares of the GroupBox are properly transparent. My suggestion is to look at the parent container.

Also the GroupBox label may become hard to read in some cases, once the top strip is transparent.